# Guarantee the order of Array processing .each() Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, foreach

In groovy I know that the .each() loop on a Map has [no guarantee](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#each) of the order of when contents are processed. What about the .each() on an Array of objs? My thoughts were that the .each() on an array would safely give me the expected order every time, but talking with a friend the other day, he said he doesn't think the order will be guaranteed. For example:

```
MyObj[] x = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ];

x.each(){ obj ->
  //what order will my objs come in?
}
```

Also, what about:

```
x.eachWithIndex() { obj, i ->
  println(i); //what order will they come in?
}
```

Can I guarantee the order of my .each() or .eachWithIndex() loop?

[Reference](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is guaranteed to be the order of the collection.

Don't get the closure based looping confused with concurrency or parallelism. It's just simple iteration in a single thread.  The comment about Maps just reinforces that Java Maps have no guaranteed ordering.  Note that groovy uses LinkedHashMaps by default.  Those *do* have a guaranteed ordering: by insertion order.

Also note that with GPars, you can use parallel collections where the above doesn't apply.

Comment: awesome thanks! You said that groovy uses LinkedHashMaps by default, would my example code be a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Map literals declared like `[key: value]` will be LinkedHashMaps.